# Determine if two files are hard linked on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I can create a hard link by:

```
import win32file
win32file.CreateHardLink(src, dst)
```

What I need to do is determine if 2 files (src, dst) are already hard linked, and if not delete dst and create the link.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why not use `os.link` to create hard links?

Comment: Good suggestion - but os.link isn't supported in Windows for Python 2.7

Comment: I added the 2.7 tag to highlight this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to martineau's pointer, I've found the following article which gives some working Python code to do almost precisely what I want:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/see_if_two_files_are_the_same_file.html

Comment: You should copy relevant piece of code into answer, because link can go dead.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Google:

In Python 3, use [`os.path.samefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile).

This works in both Windows and Unix.

Comment: Great answer! However, this is only supported on Windows in Python 3, which unfortunately I'm not able to rely on in this project just yet.